# Crash on response of requestAccessForMediaType when asking permission for camera

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, cardio

I have an issue for devices using iOS 10, where on first launch of app, when I try to use camera, appears the pop-up describes the reason app needs to use the camera, and either the user accepts it either declines it, the app will crash.
After that, application crashes on splash screen.

This issue happens only if the user tries to use the camera the first time the app launched. If user will not use the camera the first time and terminates the app, the next time the camera opens properly.

I added also the NSCameraUsageDescription in my info.plist but the only think is changing is the message in pop-up.

Comment: put plist description ios

Comment: I 've already added a description on plist with no success.

Comment: is descriptions as like $(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to use your camera

Comment: Mention crash which your are getting

Comment: I cannot run it from xCode and catch the crash since I still use v7.3.1 and the error is occurred for iOS 10. But from device console where I see the logs doesn't give any explanation for terminating the app.

Comment: @KKRocks yes the description is in that way written

Answer (score 0):

The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: I 've already mentioned that I have added a NSCameraUsageDescription key on my info.plist with the purpose my app needs to use the camera.